# React Native UseEffect hook return function never gets called

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to update date after 12 am. So, I am setting a recursive timer to calculate seconds till next day and update If user is on the same screen. I am noticing that the timer unsubscribe function never gets called (whether the app goes in background, app is killed or navigation state changes)

```
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(new Date());
  let timer;

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("RENDERING");
    updateDateAfter12am();
    return () => {
      console.log("CLEARING TIMER");
      clearTimeout(timer);
    };
  }, []);

  const updateDateAfter12am = () => {
    const currentDate = new Date();
    const secondsUntilEndOfDate = getSecondsUntilEndOfDate(currentDate);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      if (isSameDay(selectedDate, currentDate)) {
        setSelectedDate(new Date());
      }
      updateDateAfter12am();
    }, secondsUntilEndOfDate * 1000);
  };

  const isSameDay = (d1, d2) => {
    return (
      d1.getFullYear() === d2.getFullYear() &&
      d1.getMonth() === d2.getMonth() &&
      d1.getDate() === d2.getDate()
    );
  };

  const getSecondsUntilEndOfDate = (d) => {
    var h = d.getHours();
    var m = d.getMinutes();
    var s = d.getSeconds();
    return 24 * 60 * 60 - h * 60 * 60 - m * 60 - s;
  };
```

Comment: Instead of let timer, use let timer = useRef(), this way you keep the same reference. then, to update it's value timer.current= some value

Comment: @lissettdm Thanks for reaching out. I have tried useRef but the issue is still there

Comment: Can you provide a codesandbox link?

Answer (score 1):

I have created a very simple code sandbox to test your code, and it looks like it is behaving correctly: the `useEffect` cleanup function is being called whenever the component is unmounted, as stated in [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup).

[image: GIF showcasing that it works fine]

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [mounted, setMounted] = React.useState(true);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => setMounted((prev) => !prev)}>Mount/Unmount</button>
      {mounted && <Test />}
    </div>
  );
}

const Test = () => {
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = React.useState(new Date());
  let timer;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("RENDERING");
    updateDateAfter12am();
    return () => {
      console.log("CLEARING TIMER");
      clearTimeout(timer);
    };
  }, []);

  const updateDateAfter12am = () => {
    const currentDate = new Date();
    const secondsUntilEndOfDate = getSecondsUntilEndOfDate(currentDate);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      if (isSameDay(selectedDate, currentDate)) {
        setSelectedDate(new Date());
      }
      updateDateAfter12am();
    }, secondsUntilEndOfDate * 1000);
  };

  const isSameDay = (d1, d2) => {
    return (
      d1.getFullYear() === d2.getFullYear() &&
      d1.getMonth() === d2.getMonth() &&
      d1.getDate() === d2.getDate()
    );
  };

  const getSecondsUntilEndOfDate = (d) => {
    var h = d.getHours();
    var m = d.getMinutes();
    var s = d.getSeconds();
    return 24 * 60 * 60 - h * 60 * 60 - m * 60 - s;
  };

  return <p>{selectedDate.toString()}</p>;
};
```

[image: Edit SO-66212721]

So the problem might be that you are not actually unmounting your component. If you need help with that, you should post a [Complete, Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. The issue is in react native. Probably the component doesn't unmounts when in background or when killed (by removing from recent apps)? 
I generated an expo snack: https://snack.expo.io/@rabiarashid/36b0d5 but can't test it online as the device gets disconnected when back button is pressed (moved in background)

Comment: I also get this warning "Setting a timer for a long period of time, i.e. multiple minutes, is a performance and correctness issue on Android as it keeps
the timer module awake, and timers can only be called when the app is in the foreground. See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981 for more info."

I just want a timer when the app is in foreground and is focused at this particular component/screen.

Comment: @artsnr I am not into react-native, but the problem is not related to the useEffect per se. I don't think you can do anything if the app is all of a sudden closed (just guessing here), but for changes in the app state you might need to use this https://reactnative.dev/docs/appstate and for the navigation you can check at this related question https://stackoverflow.com/a/48538873/10648865